# Xbuntu brightness unable to change through Power Management

Tags: power-management, brightness

I already looked through the forums, but I couldn't find any thing that fixed my problem. For the sake of future reference, my computer is a P670 from Eluktronics. I have already contacted their support, but they don't know GNU+Linux.

My brightness can be modified by the following, but the Power Manager plugin and the function keys don't change it. I can't figure out how to link the two despite looking around.

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness [value]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am seriously stumped on the problems.

Comment: you should post these two as separate questions.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh Done